# Minecraft IntelliJ IDEA debugger on host

Tags: debugging, server, minecraft, host

When coding on IntelliJ IDEA I would like to use a debugger while coding a minecraft plugin. Unconviniently the server is runnin on a host and is using multicraft. Can i connect it to intelliJ IDEA or somehow use a debugger?
Ps. forgive my stupidity im a beginner on java.

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Run/Debug Configurations" and add a new configuration. Choose "Remote" and enter your remote host and debug port.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html